# PowerQuery conditional string length based on value in another column

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Goal is to change an existing column and not create a new columnn.

In Power BI I'm trying to do a conditional string length cleanup based on a product name on an existing column.

This is attempting to cleanup software code versions based on their custom schema types. Ideally I would like to do this in one step with multiple if nested if statements.

**BUSINESS LOGIC** 
If Apple, keep first 5 characters 
If Samsung, keep first 6 characters 
If Nokia, keep first 5 characters 
else return existing label

| Product | Label |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 12.23.244.12 |
| Samsung | 001.23.34-21 |
| Nokia | 4-213.2 |
| Apple | 11.22.002.12 |
| Nokia | 4-213.2 |
| Nokia | 4-213.2 |
| Samsung | 002.22.34-67 |
| Random | Rev-22-91.23 |

My current failed code looks like this:

```
= table.TransformColumns(Table.TransformRows(#"prevstep",
   (r) => Record.TransformFields( r, {
   {if r[Product] = "Apple" then Text.Start(_,5)
    else if r[Product] = "Samsung" then Text.Start(_,6)
    else if r[Product] = "Nokia" then Text.Start(_,5)
    else _}
   }))
```

**Desired Output**

| Product | Label |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 12.23 |
| Samsung | 001.23 |
| Nokia | 4-213 |
| Apple | 11.22 |
| Nokia | 4-213 |
| Nokia | 4-213 |
| Samsung | 002.22 |
| Random | Rev-22-91.23 |

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to transform that column using your logic:

***Using the `TransformRows` method you show:***

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("bY47CoAwEETvsrUJySQoll7AQsuQIqCI+AXR87sJKBa2783OrHNU7fvcU0YaEkbCWqlBPnPUhuU414GVUjo6YwV0UvU2jYFFBHyT2NvDWUil8PT8hf/Ydw+xg/fyIqkmrN22sGn6SwCijP+Q9zc=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Product = _t, Label = _t]),

    xformProducts={"Apple","Samsung","Nokia"},
    xformLength = {5,6,5},
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Product", type text}, {"Label", type text}}),

    xform = Table.TransformRows(#"Changed Type", (r)=> Record.TransformFields(r,{"Label", 
        each try Text.Start(_, xformLength{List.PositionOf(xformProducts,r[Product])}) otherwise _})),
    
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(xform, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"Product", "Label"}, {"Product", "Label"})
    
in
    #"Expanded Column1"
```

You can also use the **`ReplaceValue`** method:

```
let 
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("bY47CoAwEETvsrUJySQoll7AQsuQIqCI+AXR87sJKBa2783OrHNU7fvcU0YaEkbCWqlBPnPUhuU414GVUjo6YwV0UvU2jYFFBHyT2NvDWUil8PT8hf/Ydw+xg/fyIqkmrN22sGn6SwCijP+Q9zc=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Product = _t, Label = _t]),

    xformProducts={"Apple","Samsung","Nokia"},
    xformLength = {5,6,5},
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Product", type text}, {"Label", type text}}),
    #"Replace Labels" = Table.ReplaceValue(
        #"Changed Type",
        each [Product],
        each [Label],
        (x,y,z)=> try Text.Start(x, xformLength{List.PositionOf(xformProducts,y)}) otherwise z,
        {"Label"})

in 
    #"Replace Labels"
```

Both result in:

[image]

*I'm not sure which one will be more efficient. Diagnostics on these small tables shows too much variability to come to a definite conclusion*

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So the table i need to clean up has about 8M rows of data... I would definitely want to test this for efficiency. Also, I have about 20+ different products that need rules. I'll reply back with which one comes out more efficient,.

Comment: @Martin_ Thanks. And so long as the rules are similar to what you show, you can just extend the two Lists `xformProducts` and `xformLength` to account for the other products.

Comment: Instead of using two lists and potentially getting your values out of order, I would create a record like **xLength = [ Apple = 5, Samsung = 6, Nokia = 5]** and get the length using **Record.Field(xLength, r[Product] )**

Comment: @spinfuzer That is a good alternative, especially if there is a long list of items.